# how to fix login form in ajax dialog for symfony2

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am implementing a dialog for my login form in symfony2, it works well except I would want to handle the return with some more logic, now I don't know how to do that since the firewall configuration picks up the login submission.

What happens is that if login failed, the html of my dialog is replaced with the new html returned by the login controller, this is all fine.
But if a successful login attempt occurs, the html of my login dialog is replaced with my entire site (since a successful symfony2 login will redirect to the start page...).

In flat PHP I would add this to the login controller

```
if (login_successful) {
  return "success";
}
```

and in my dialog function put

```
if (returned_data == "success") {
  refresh_page(); // or location.href('something')
}
else
{
  // replace dialog_html with the returned html
}
```

But as I look to the action taking care of the login form submission i FOS user bundle, this is what I find

```
public function checkAction()
{
    throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
}
```

So I realize this is all taken care of behind the scenes in symfony2, can I even get at this then?

Actual sample code (JS)...

```
function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
  form = $(form);
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: (form.attr('method')),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            //Success-token is passed, so reload page (will close dialog and load the logged-in start screen since user is now fully authenticated
            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            //Form is returned, probably with errors, so let user try again...
            $('#formDialog').html(data);
        }
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

and the form...

```
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post" id="login-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <TD><label for="username">Login</label></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" placeholder="användare" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" /></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><label for="password">Lösenord</label></TD>
            <TD><input type="password" placeholder="lösenord" id="password" name="_password" /></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><label for="remember_me">Kom ihåg mig</label></TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" /></TD>
        </TR>
        <!--
        <TR>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD align="right"><input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Logga in" /></TD>
        </TR>
        -->
    </TABLE>

</form>
```

---

As per m2mdas suggestion below, I now have these set up:

config.yml

```
#My services
services:
    my.authentication.success_handler:
        class:     Hemekonomi\UserBundle\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
        parent:    security.authentication.success_handler
```

my userbundle now has this class

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
   public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if(true === $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new Response("success");
        }

        //default redirect operation.
        return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }

}
```

... and the security.yml has...

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            success_handler: my.authentication.success_handler
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

The error I get is this

```
RuntimeException: The parent definition "security.authentication.success_handler" defined for definition "my.authentication.success_handler" does not exist.
```

Could it have something to do with formatting, is it different in xml/yml? I am no expert in either so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this solution (thanks to m2mdas & http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/set-up-authenticationsuccesshandler.html)

config.yml

```
#My services
parameters:
    security.authentication.success_handler.class: MyApp\UserBundle\Resources\AuthenticationSuccessHandler

services:
    security.authentication.success_handler:
        class: %security.authentication.success_handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments:  ['@router', '@security.user.entity_manager']
```

security.wml

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

successhandler (including slightly more functionality than what I asked for, might use this later on):

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\UserBundle\Resources;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;


/**
 * Custom authentication success handler
 */
class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

   private $router;
   private $em;

   /**
    * Constructor
    * @param RouterInterface   $router
    * @param EntityManager     $em
    */
   public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, EntityManager $em)
   {
      $this->router = $router;
      $this->em = $em;
   }


   function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
   {

        if(true === $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new Response("success");
        }

        //default redirect operation.
        $uri = $this->router->generate('MyAppSkrivbordBundle_homepage');
        return new RedirectResponse($uri);


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `success_handler` and `failure_handler` options of the firewall config. For example

Success handler class,

```
namespace Your\NameSpace;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
   public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if(true === $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new Response("success");
        }

        //default redirect operation.
        return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }

}
```

Failure handler class,

```
namespace Your\NameSpace;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if(true === $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new Response("failure");
        }

        //default redirect operation.
        return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);

    }
}
```

Service definitions(xml)

```
    <service id="my.authentication.success_handler" class="Your\NameSpace\AuthenticationSuccessHandler" parent="security.authentication.success_handler"/>

    <service id="my.authentication.failure_handler" class="Your\NameSpace\AuthenticationFailureHandler" parent="security.authentication.failure_handler"/>
```

OR, yml service definition,

```
my.authentication.success_handler:
    class: Your\NameSpace\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    parent: security.authentication.success_handler

my.authentication.failure_handler:
    class: Your\NameSpace\AuthenticationFailureHandler
    parent: security.authentication.failure_handler
```

And finally in `security.yml`,

```
security:
    firewall:
        your_firewall:
            #...
            form_login:
                #...
                success_handler: my.authentication.success_handler
                failure_handler: my.authentication.failure_handler
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I am almost there and this seems just what I needed. I get an error however, I have updated my code above to reflect your solution.

Comment: or should I perhaps not have put the handler in one of my bundles, should it go in a specific place?

Comment: Sorry for putting xml configuration. I have extended the default success and failure handler. Advantage is that the new services obey redirect options defined in `securit.yml` or referer redirection for normal pages. Added yml service config.